# Changing class field by this field

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
abstract class A
{
    public Master parent;
    public virtual void DoSomething()
}

class Master
{
    public A a;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        a.DoSomething();
    }
}

class A1 : A
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        parent.a = new A2();
    }
}

class A2 : A
{
    public override void DoSomething()
    {
        parent.a = new A1();
    }
}
```

And I do this:

```
Master m = new Master();
m.a = new A1();
m.a.parent = m;
m.DoSomething();
```

Is it good to change m.a this way? Can GarbageCollector delete A1 object when A1.DoSomething() is running? When A1 changes m.a to A2, A1 has no reference, so I have no idea is it safe.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual methord have body else you have to made this methord as abstract using abstract keyword.

```
 abstract class A
    {
        public Master Parent;
            public virtual void DoSomething()
            {
                //This block is missing in your code
            }
    }


 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var m = new Master();
        m.a = new A1 {Parent = m};
        m.DoSomething();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read up on [circular references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716190(v=vs.60).aspx) and [how to get rid of them](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nickmalik/archive/2005/03/18/398601.aspx). Is there a reason you can't change a from the Master class?

```
abstract class A
{
    public static A GetNextA(AType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case AType.A1: return new A1();
            case AType.A2: return new A2();
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    public abstract AType DoSomething();
}

class Master
{
    public A a;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        AType nextAType = a.DoSomething();
        a = A.GetNextA(nextAType);
    }
}

class A1 : A
{
    public override AType DoSomething()
    {
        //do Work
        return AType.A2;
    }
}

class A2 : A
{
    public override AType DoSomething()
    {
        //do Different Work
        return AType.A1;
    }
}

enum AType
{
    A1,
    A2
}
```

and use them like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var m = new Master();
    m.a = new A1();
    m.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: I can't do it this way, because A1 class decide if it should be replaced by A2

Comment: Can you use a return from A.DoSomething to determine next A? I will edit my post to show what I mean.

Comment: I haven't tested to see, but I assume your way probably works. However, it's best to avoid having nested classes hold a reference to their parent whenever possible.

Comment: @MaxHampton A.DoSomething: virtual or abstract members cannot be private.

Comment: Oops, yeah, methods are private by default, set it to public, my mistake.

Comment: in this Code A.GetNextA is also inaccessable due to its protection level @MaxHampton

Comment: See previous comment. And thanks for pointing that out for me.

Comment: really i didn't see.K :)

Comment: But in this solution A.GetNextA(nextAType) will always return new instance and all previous data in A will be lost. What if I use events? Something like: A has some event "ChangeEvent" and Master sets proper method?

Comment: @petros From what I can see that is what your original code is doing also. If you only want one A1 and one A2 to exist, you want something like the Singleton pattern.

Comment: Actually I was thinking about Template method pattern. I make game in XNA and I try to design some MainMenu. For example abstract class GameModule and inherited Menu, NewGame, Option, Credits (with methods Update and Draw). When Update method in Menu detect user's choice to go into options, it change actual module to Option, and then game is using Option class to Update and Draw

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safe. The GC will collect the first instance of A1 when DoSomething() is done. But it looks like, you need to set the parent of A2 in A1.DoSomething()